# Given the situation, how should I store user information?

Tags: php, node.js, jwt, access-token, stateless

Currently building the front-end using NodeJS, of an application that has the back-end built in PHP. Now, although the PHP-based API is not currently embracing JWT, the application is working towards being stateless. So it does make use of tokens, and most of the endpoints expect a token to enable further processing. However, these tokens are not JWT and so not intelligent enough to store user information. Since certain bits of information are constantly required throughout the application... what would be the sensible way to deal with this information requirement i.e. user name, user image, etc. Would it make sense to store the information within localStorage until the application is logged out? Perhaps we should introduce some kind of caching mechanism like Redis. But wouldn't that go against the concept of trying to be stateless? I know this sounds contradictory but... is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: Building frontend with NodeJS? Sure? Btw: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Angular to be exact... but coupled with NodeJS. So, yes.

Comment: So your building the frontend with angular. NodeJS is the backend part of your application. NodeJS is nothing else than serverside JS.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Our front-end is completely decoupled from our backend... in fact, they are on different servers altogether. So when I say front-end, I mean the entire front... and that includes NodeJS, which is what is powering our front-end.

Comment: @Twinfriends For your information, have a look at :-https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/10/07/node-js-and-the-new-web-front-end/

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look. And sorry for not answering your question, but I can't help you.